# How large can Protege import an Owl file?

Tags: protege

I have a 2MB OWL file that I downloaded from the web. I tried to open it in Protege 5.2, it didn't report any issue or message, but simply load nothing in the UI. I suspect it might be due to the file size?

What's the largest file size that Protege can support? Thanks,

Comment: It depends on the specs of the computer you running Protege, but in general it can easily (though it will take a while) load files of a 100 MB. So no, I don't think it shows nothing due to the size of the file, but rather that  there is some error in the file. Check the logs for additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hardcoded limit on the file size - there are other limits, such as the number of XML entities that will be expanded.

However any such issue should raise an error. If you're seeing no errors in the console, something else must be happening. A possibility is that your ontology imports remote ontologies and these are either very large or served by slow sites, so Protege would appear to freeze or do nothing while waiting for the download to finish.